# Angular 4 how to add (click) directive dependent on page component is used in

Tags: angular, function, click

I am just getting started with Angular 4 and I like the idea of discrete reusable components. I am trying to see if am also able to reduce the amount of repeated code that I write.

As an example. Lets say I have a suppliers component, with a supplier-table.component.ts that provides a sortable and searchable table for my suppliers. I may want to include that table in different parts of my site, but depending on what page the user is on, I want to trigger a different function when the user clicks a supplier name.

- Supplier table on the find a PO page opens a list of suppliers PO's
- Supplier table on the find an invoice page opens a list of supplier Invoices.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `supplier-table.ts` component having `supplier-table` template. In your main module template say `app.component.html` you include the template:

```
<supplier-table #t1> </supplier-table>
```

And on the click event you could invoke `t1.x()` or `t1.y()` depending upon the requirement. The corresponding functions (`x()` & `y()` in this case) would generate different versions of the `supplier-table` from within the `supplier-table` component.

Comment: I used this in a project with material table. Different functions would attach different data source to the table depending on the requirement.

Comment: Material was just an example I mentioned. You could you it way you like

Comment: @HBK Could you elaborate slightly more on how this would work?

Comment: @HBK I like the idea of passing in a param when the supplier-table is loaded, then in the onClick function use that param in a switch statement to either redirect to a route or dynamically load lets say the Invoice component.

Comment: @PrestonDocks Sure thing! That could be accomplished